# How to get all elements in DOM and text without tags

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

for(var b = 0; b < elements.length; b++) {
     // Here is DOM elemenets with tags
     // I need to get here DOM elements with HTML tags and DOM elements without HTML tags.
}
```

How I can do it? Thanks in advance.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9B4B/

(vanilla.js)

Comment: This is interesting. Can you explain more what you mean by "elements with tags" and "elements without tags"? Maybe some examples so we know precisely what you're asking?

Comment: I think he means elements without a class or ID?

Comment: I think the OP means elements and nodes.

Comment: @CharlieS, jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9B4B/

Comment: What is a DOM element without tag?  Do you mean no child elements?

Comment: @jfriend00, just text without HTML tag. Please, see my jsfiddle example.

Comment: @owl I see, you're trying to look for text nodes within the body (they aren't actually elements). I'm assuming this is meant to be recursive?

Comment: they still will be children of `<body>`. you can't have content outside document which is `<html>` and primary object in javascript on page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it appears from your jsFiddle that what you want is the text that is in the `<body>`, but not in any other tag.  I call that "top level text".  You can collect the top level text nodes like this by iterating through the childNodes of the body element and collecting just the text nodes.  Any text in another tag will be a child of that tag, not a direct child of the body.

```
function getTopTextNodes() {
    var textNodes = [];
    var topNodes = document.body.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < topNodes.length; i++) {
        if (topNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
            textNodes.push(topNodes[i]);
        }
    }
    return textNodes;
}
```

Or, if you want the blocks of text:

```
function getTopText() {
    var text = [];
    var topNodes = document.body.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < topNodes.length; i++) {
        if (topNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
            text.push(topNodes[i].nodeValue);
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Keep in mind that what appears in the document as a single piece of text could be in multiple neighboring text nodes.  If you want to combine text from consecutive text nodes, that can be done like this:

```
function getTopTextCombined() {
    var text = [];
    var lastNodeType;
    var topNodes = document.body.childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < topNodes.length; i++) {
        if (topNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
            if (lastNodeType === 3) {
                text[text.length - 1] += topNodes[i].nodeValue;
            } else {
                text.push(topNodes[i].nodeValue);
            }
        }
        lastNodeType = topNodes[i].nodeType;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Note that different browsers will put things into text nodes slightly differently.  In Chrome, you will get some text nodes with only whitespace in them which you may need to ignore if you just want visible text and there may be \n characters in the text too.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your fiddle, I think I get what you mean. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/b5LwP/1/

```
var elements = document.body.childNodes;

for(var b = 0; b < elements.length; b++) {
    if (elements[b].textContent.length) {
        console.log(elements[b].textContent);
    }
}
```

From the markup

```
<div class="div-class">I have a tag.</div>
I don't have a tag.
<div class="div-class">I have a tag too.</div>
```

the console will log

```
I have a tag.
I don't have a tag.
I have a tag too.
```

Answer (score -1):

I think JQuery `.contents()` with filtering is what you need:
http://api.jquery.com/contents/

> "Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .contents() method allows us to search throughthe immediate children
>   of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object
>   from the matching elements. The .contents() and .children() methods
>   are similar, except that the former includes text nodes as well as
>   HTML elements in the resulting jQuery object."

---

You can filter to only text nodes further using code as follows:

```
$("parent").contents()
    .filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3;
})
```

Comment: And, the question isn't a jQuery question.

Comment: Jquery provides a solution to this problem. It's not a Jquery question, its a question that JQuery answers.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - use `.children()` for only HTML tags. use `.contents()` to get both.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Jquery also provides filters to get only text nodes using `.filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 3; })`

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky: ah yes, brainfail. That wouldn't be too bad if the OP wanted to use jQuery, except if you wanted deep traversal.